# Cloud Storage Insufficient Permission while using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am setting up the IaC with Terraform in GCP. When I run the pipeline I am getting below error

```
Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: querying Cloud Storage failed: googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions
```

Here is my backend gcs:

```
data "tf_state" "my_app" {
  backend = "gcs"
  config = {
    bucket = "my_bucket"
    prefix = "envs/${module.variables.environment}/my_app"
  }
}
```

I am able to access the content in my_bucket on console, but getting an error while running with terraform.

can anyone please let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: 1) How are you authorizing Terraform? 2) Try the command **gcloud auth application-default login** then run Terraform.

Comment: @raj S, As the issue has been resolved, can you  please mark the answer as accepted for the greater visibility to community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now declared Google application credentials in gitlab CI/CD variables in a json format and then using it in .gitlab.yml file.

[image]

```
# Environments definition
.dev:
  variables:
    PROJECT_ID: <projecct-id>
    DEPLOYED_MODULES: "my-module"
    GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}
    TF_LOG: ""
  environment:
    name: dev
  only:
    refs:
    - develop
```

Answer (score 0):

We have used as below to reference state file which is GCS

```
terraform {
  backend "gcs" {}
}
```

Then in .gitlab-ci.yaml

```
before_script:
  - terraform init -input=false -backend-config=env/dev/gcs-bucket.tfvars
```

Content of `gcs-bucket.tfvars`

```
bucket  = "your-bucket-name"
prefix  = "folder name"
```